Transport mode IPSEC on only one of two IPs using StrongSwan
I have a ubuntu server with two NICs, configured with two different IPv4 (on the same network, on the internet directly, no NAT involved), let's call them [ip1] and [ip2]. I am trying to set up transport mode IPSEC on [ip2] but not [ip1] (so that [ip2] requires IPSEC, [ip1] does not support IPSEC).
My problem is that right now it seems that IPSEC is not running on either ip (I can connect to both ips from a client with no IPSEC set up, and I can't connect to [ip2] from a windows client with IPSEC setup ).
My /etc/ipsec.conf file looks like this:
config setup

conn myipsec
       authby=secret
       auto=route
       keyexchange=ikev1
       left=[ip2]
       right=%any
       type=transport

conn noipsec
      left=[ip1]
      right=%any
      type=passthrough
      auto=route

My /etc/ipsec.secrets looks like this (key redacted):
[ip2] : PSK "[redacted]"

I tried running "ipsec restart" or even rebooting the machine after any change.
ifconfig returns (ips redacted as well):
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet [ip1]  netmask 255.255.255.240  broadcast [ip1broadcast]
        RX packets 12666  bytes 1467048 (1.4 MB)
        TX packets 1731  bytes 1448410 (1.4 MB)

eno2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet [ip2]  netmask 255.255.255.240  broadcast [ip1broadcast]
        RX packets 5077  bytes 394169 (394.1 KB)
        TX packets 79  bytes 3886 (3.8 KB)

and this is the output of "ipsec statusall":
Status of IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.9.13, Linux 6.8.0-41-generic, x86_64):
  uptime: 2 minutes, since Aug 25 09:41:42 2024
  malloc: sbrk 2158592, mmap 0, used 550544, free 1608048
  worker threads: 11 of 16 idle, 5/0/0/0 working, job queue: 0/0/0/0, scheduled: 0
  loaded plugins: charon aesni aes rc2 sha2 sha1 md5 mgf1 random nonce x509 revocation constraints pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey pem openssl pkcs8 fips-prf gmp agent xcbc hmac kdf gcm drbg attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default connmark stroke updown eap-mschapv2 xauth-generic counters
Listening IP addresses:
  [ip1]
  [ip2]
Connections:
     myipsec:  [ip2]...%any  IKEv1
     myipsec:   local:  [[ip2]] uses pre-shared key authentication
     myipsec:   remote: uses pre-shared key authentication
     myipsec:   child:  dynamic === dynamic TRANSPORT
     noipsec:  [ip1]...%any  IKEv1/2
     noipsec:   local:  [[ip1]] uses public key authentication
     noipsec:   remote: uses public key authentication
     noipsec:   child:  dynamic === dynamic PASS
Shunted Connections:
     noipsec:  dynamic === dynamic PASS
Routed Connections:
     myipsec{1}:  ROUTED, TRANSPORT, reqid 1
     myipsec{1}:   0.0.0.0/0 === 0.0.0.0/0
Security Associations (0 up, 0 connecting):
  none

The only other thing about this server is that I have iptables rules to ensure that only certain IPs can connect to the server but I doubt this is related:
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s [ip1 network] -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s [other ip] -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s [other ip] -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s [other ip] -j ACCEPT

Can you think of anything I have done wrong such that IPSEC is ineffective on [ip2]?
